# a set of lesbegue measure zero

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure

Assume that $f \colon R\rightarrow \bar{R}$, which is given by 
$f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ and let $\Gamma=\left\{(x,f(x)):x\in \mathbb R\right\}$. 
Show that, the Lebesgue measure of $\Gamma$ is zero.

The idea is to cover the curve by rectangles such that the sum of their areas (measures) is smaller  than $\varepsilon$ for each $\varepsilon >0$. The problem is how to do that near the point $x=0$, on which the function is discontinuous?

Comment: x= 0 has nothing to do with this.  There is **no** point (0, f(0)) in the set.

Comment: near $x=0$ from left and wright!

Comment: Hint: f is a Riemann integrable function.

Comment: and so what please?!

Comment: Also, the problem isn't correctly stated. To fix it you can either consider $f$ as a function from  $\mathbb{R}$ to $\bar{\mathbb{R}}$ or you can change the domain to $\mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}$

Comment: Do you remember an almost obvious result of calculus that sometimes is called the Cauchy criterion for Riemann integrability? this is actually the formalization of the idea that you said.

Comment: Thank you  very much, I have edited the Problem.

Comment: What is Lebesgue measure on $\bar{\mathbb R}$ ?  (I need to know because you are talking about a subset of ${\mathbb R}\times\bar{\mathbb R}$.)

Comment: @kimchilover $\bar{\mathbb{R}}=\mathbb{R}\cup \{\infty\} \cup \{-\infty\}$ so you can define for every $A\subset \bar{\mathbb{R}}$ its measure as $\bar{\lambda}(A)=\lambda(A\cap \mathbb{R})$.

Comment: @HeroKenzan So you are saying $\bar\lambda(\{\infty\}\cup\{-\infty\})=0$?

Comment: yeah, I think that's the usual.

Comment: If we consider the interval $]0,1]$, we can divide it  with $n$  divisions and  cover the curve by a countable rectangles. But when we sum there areas, we need to find the limit as $n\rightarrow \infinity$

Comment: Let $\lfloor \Omega\rfloor$ be the greatest integer less than or equal to $\Omega$.  Then the function
$$x\mapsto \begin{cases} \lfloor 1/x\rfloor & \text{if } \lfloor 1/x\rfloor\le n \\[8pt]
n & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$ could help you evaluate the integral over $(0,1]$?

Comment: Yes it helps but how to integrate? I think that  it helps in constructing  rectangles contain the curve in $]0,1]$! thank you very much and please some additional hep is more appreciated!

Comment: For $\epsilon >0$ and $n\in \mathbb N$ consider  $S(\epsilon,n)=$ $\{(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2: 1/(2n)<x<1/n \land  |y-f(x)|<\epsilon 2^{-n}\}$ and  consider $T(\epsilon)=\cup_{n\in  \mathbb N}S(\epsilon,n).$...... Then $T(\epsilon)\supset \{(x,f(x)): 0<x<1\}$ and the measure $m(T(\epsilon))\leq \sum_{n\in \mathbb N}m(S(\epsilon,n))<\epsilon .$

Comment: Thank you very much @DanielWainfleet

Comment: To cover $\{(x.f(x): x>1\} $ you just reflect $T(\epsilon)$ about the line $y=x.$

Comment: Thank you very much @DanielWainfleet